# F# Type declaration possible ala Haskell?

Tags: haskell, f#

I've looked a number of sources: it seems not possible to declare a type definition in F# ala Haskell:

```
' haskell type def:
myFunc :: int -> int
```

I'd like to use this type-def style in F#--FSI is happy to echo back to me:

```
fsi> let myType x = x +1;;

val myType : int -> int
```

I'd like to be explicit about the type def signature in F# as in Haskell. Is there a way to do this? I'd like to write in F#:

```
//invalid F#
myFunc : int -> int
myFunc x = x*2
```

Comment: @Jon: interesting position. Why is this 'known-to-be-crap'? It's totally optional in Haskell, and I personally find it quite helpful as a way for me to sketch out how I want my types to line up. I'm interested in what you see the problem with type defs to be.

Comment: @Kevin: Resorting to type annotations almost always reflects a deficiency in the type system, usually that advanced features would otherwise result in obfuscated error messages. That happens when you overshoot the sweet spot that ML hit by adding more advanced forms of inference to the type system. The workaround in OCaml was to add type annotations to argument definitions when using polymorphic variants or objects. The workaround in Haskell was to make type annotations ubiquitous due to the ubiquity of type classes (and the absence of any alternatives).

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the clarification. I think we are talking about two different reasons for these annotations, however. I don't want type annotations for the compiler: I want it for me! In other words, I find them helpful to clarify in unambiguous terms what I need the different functions to do. I find that simply though working out the type signatures I can get a long ways towards solving the problem.

Comment: @Kevin: If you want this only as a stop-gap measure during early development and you are not happy with using an fsi file then you might consider writing `let startServer : IPAddress -> int -> unit = fun x -> failwith "Not yet implemented"`.

Comment: @Jon: Type classes do not result in a need for explicit type signatures or type annotations. Haskell98, which includes type classes, is fully inferrable. So too are most standard uses of multi-parameter type classes. Explicit type annotations or signatures are generally required for higher order polymorphism, which is proven to not be fully inferrable. There are plenty of useful functions with higher ranked types, and it seems silly to consider providing users with the *option* of using them as a "deficiency in the type system."

Comment: @sclv: You have given a correct answer to the wrong question. Ask yourself why type annotations are ubiquitous in Haskell in practice even though they are rarely actually required in theory.

Comment: @Jon: I gave a correct answer to your incorrect claim that type annotations in Haskell are ubiquitous due to the ubiquity of type classes. Even in the absence of a need for an explicit type signature, one may serve (among other things) to document code, to enforce usage, and to improve the locality of error messages.

Comment: @sclv: You say "...your incorrect claim..." and yet you then concede that type annotations are needlessly added in Haskell because they "improve the locality of error messages". And they are worthless documentation given that the IDE can already provide the inferred type (unless you have a deficient IDE as well as a deficient type system).

Comment: @Jon: Type signatures improve the locality of error messages in any type-inferred language. The more polymorphic your code is able to be (i.e., the more correct expressions that a given language can type), then, in general, the more likely that error messages will have poor locality in the absence of explicit type signatures. If you write a well-typed function whose type is not what was intended (i.e. which is logically incorrect), would you prefer to know at the definition site or only a call site? I know which sounds better to me.

Comment: @Jon: I've noticed from your comments that you seem to be incredibly defensive of F#. Your bias is understandable due to wanting to protect your F# consulting company and publications, but the intellegence you no doubt posses would be better used to recognize that F# is certainly not perfect, and could certainly take a few pages from Haskell (which is also not perfect). As far as functional languages go, these two are quite a bit different, and both could certainly benifit from language contructs employed within the other.

Comment: @Jon:  Furthermore, type annotations do not imply a defeciancy in the type system anymore than comments imply a defeciency in the syntax of the language (that is to say, not at all). A small list of things in F# that annoy me personally, are banana tags (they're incredibly ugly) and lazy evaluation (a big pain to implement transparently). You could no doubt use your clout to get the F# team to revisit these two aspects of the language, as they have no idea who I am. :)

Comment: @Paul: You have forgotten that any vested interest I have is in *both* sides of this argument. That is just a convenient way to disregard the opinion of any who has studied it but does not share your own belief. Anyone can always use such a pseudo-justification when wading in after-the-fact to question a carefully crafted design but it is not constructive.

Comment: @sclv: Sure, the difference is that poor error messages in the context of polymorphic functions in core ML are rare in practice compared to the poor error messages you get from OCaml or Haskell when using more advanced forms of inference. If you stick to core ML and have an IDE that can throwback inferred types then the error messages you get are fine.

Comment: @Jon: My judgement of course was based solely on what I've seen of a select few posts of yours here on Stack Overflow, and to be clearer it seems that you want every language to be OCaml. I could admittedly be wrong, but when something as simple, elegant, and optional (!!!) as inline type annotations (as well as type classes) are dismissed as 'bad' for vague reasons it raises some red flags. Also, it can be convenient to reply to a small subset of a post and dismiss the rest, but I'm quite sure even you agree that is not very constructive.

Comment: @Paul: "...it seems that you want every language to be OCaml". I have no idea what gave you that impression. Ad-hoc polymorphism is valuable in the context of overloading arithmetic operators but OCaml is the worst of the bunch in that context because it does no overloading whatsoever. Standard ML did it better than OCaml (int and float only). Haskell did it differently (typeclasses for complete generality but unpredictably awful performance). F# did it best in practice so far (compile-time resolution guarantees performance and it is adequately extensible).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to keep readable type declarations separately from the implementation, you can use 'fsi' files (F# Signature File). The 'fsi' contains just the types and usually also comments - you can see some good examples in the source of F# libraries. You would create two files like this:

```
// Test.fsi
val myFunc : int -> int

// Test.fs
let myFunx x = x + 1
```

This works for compiled projects, but you cannot use this approach easily with F# Interactive.

Comment: I find the Haskell Type def style (and the .fsi way) such as useful way to 'sketch' in F#. any idea why FSI doesn't support this--and why you can't just do these sigs in line? Is that more of the OCaml tradition?

Comment: @Kevin: I'm not really sure, but I agree that the Haskell way looks more readable then mixed header/type annotations. It is probably the OCaml tradition, because I don't think there is any technical issue with this. Writing them inline would make sense... (Another question is whether this is worth the limited F# team resources at this point)

Comment: thanks Tomas. Just for the record, F# team, pretty please? in-line time annotations?

Comment: I would like them too, but sorry, the ship has sailed for syntax here, and we've no plans for an 'additive' change.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979084/what-features-would-you-add-remove-or-change-in-f

Comment: Also note that the .fsi is checked after the .fs, so you might still need some type annotations in the .fs to make the type inferencer happy.

Comment: @Tomas: This is possible. Don Syme actually asked me if I wanted this and I said "no". :-)

Answer (score 29):

The usual way is to do `let myFunc (x:int):int = x+1`.

If you want to be closer to the haskell style, you can also do `let myFunc : int -> int = fun x -> x+1`.

Comment: I know you can specify types that way with your actual function definition--that's not exactly what I'm asking. thanks though.

Comment: @Kevin: Make sure you understand the difference between a type annotation and a type definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in F# like so to specify the return value of myType.

```
let myType x : int = x + 1
```

You can specify the type of the parameter, too.

```
let myType (x : int) : int = x + 1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

See also [The Basic Syntax of F# - Types](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1077.entry) (which discusses this aspect a little under 'type annotations').

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use "type abbreviations" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233246.aspx)

```
type myType = int -> int
let (myFunc : myType) = (fun x -> x*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, by using lambda functions

```
myFunc : int -> int =
  fun x -> x*2
```

this also avoids the problem in haskell of writing the function name twice.

Comment: this is a duplicate of @sepp2k 's answer.