# F# assign (custom) type to a function

Tags: function, types, f#, type-constructor

For all the progress I've made in F#, I still get lost in various of the constructor and deconstructor syntax.

I'm running a recursive simulation. One of the parameters is a function for the stopping condition. I have various possible stopping conditions to choose from. I make them all have the same signature. So I decide it would be nice, and educational, to lock down these functions to a custom type--so that not just any function that happens to match the signature can be sent:

```
type StoppingCondition = | StoppingCondition of (ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool)
```

I think I'm doing this right, from tutorials, having a type name and an identical constructor name (confusing...), for a single case discriminated union. But now I can't figure out how to apply this type to an actual function:

```
let Condition1 lastRet nextRet i fl =
    true
```

How do I make Condition1 be of type StoppingCondition? I bet it's trivial. But I've tried putting StoppingCondition as the first, second or last term after let, with and without parens and colons. And everything is an error.

Thanks for the patience found here.

EDIT:

I'll try to synthesize what I lean from the four answers (as of this moment), all good:

Trying to mimic this pattern:

```
s : string = "abc"
```

I was trying to write:

```
type StoppingCondition = | StoppingCondition of (ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool)

let condition1 lastRet nextRet i fl : StoppingCondition =  // BAD 
    //wrong for a type alias, totally wrong for a union constructor
    true
    //or
let condition1 : StoppingCondition lastRet nextRet i fl = // BAD again
    true
```

or other insertions of `: Stopping Condition` (trying to prefix it, in the way that constructors go, in that one line).

Now I see that to get what I was getting at I would have to do:

```
type StoppingCondition = | StoppingCondition of (ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool)
let conditionFunc1 lastRet nextRet i fl =   //...
    true
let stoppingCondition1 = StoppingCondition conditionFunc1 
    //or
let stoppingCondition2 = StoppingCondition <| (func lastRet nextRet i fl -> false) 
    //and there's another variation or 2 below
```

And what I didn't appreciate as a big negative to this approach is how a union type is different from a type alias. A type alias `of string` admits of the string functions when declared--it really is a string and does "string things. A single case discriminated union `of string`--is not a string any more. To have it do "string things" you have to unwrap it. (Or write versions of those functions into your type (which might be wrappers of the string functions).) Likewise a type alias of my function accepts those parameters. A DU of my function is just a wrapper and doesn't take arguments. So this doesn't work with discriminated union:

```
let x = stoppingCondition1 ret1 ret2 2 3.0 // BAD
    //"stoppingCondition1 is not a function and cannot be applied"
```

And there's not enough value in my case here to work around the wrapper. But a type alias works:

```
type StoppingAlias = ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool
let stoppingCondition:StoppingAlias = fun prevRet nextRet i x -> true
let b = stoppingCondition ret1 ret2 10 1.0  // b = true
```

I may not have everything straight in what I just said, but I think I'm a lot closer.

Edit 2:

Side note. My question is about defining the type of a function. And it compares using a type alias and a union type. As I worked at trying to do these, I also learned this about using a type alias:

This works (from: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/defining-functions/ ):

```
type Adder = decimal -> decimal -> decimal
let f1 : Adder = (fun x y -> x + y)
    //or
let f2 : decimal -> decimal -> decimal = fun x y -> x + y
```

but these are wrong:

```
let (f2 : Adder) x y = x + y    // bad 
let (f3 x y) : (decimal -> decimal -> decimal) = x + y   // bad 
let (f3 : (decimal -> decimal -> decimal)) x y  = x + y  // bad
```

And some discussion on this whole issue: [F# Type declaration possible ala Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713233/f-type-declaration-possible-ala-haskell)

(And also, yeah, "assigning a type" isn't the right thing to say either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been said, you have to construct an instance of a `StoppingCondition` from an appropriate function, for example:

```
let Condition1 = StoppingCondition (fun _ _ _ _ -> true)`
```

One nice way to do this without weird indentation or extra parentheses is a backward pipe:

```
let Condition1 = StoppingCondition <| fun lastRet nextRet i fl ->
    // Add function code here
```

The signature might be long enough to justify a record type instead of four curried parameters. It's a question of style and how it'll be used; the result may look like this:

```
type MyInput =
    { LastReturn : ReturnType
      NextReturn : ReturnType
      MyInt      : int
      MyFloat    : float }

type StopCondition = StopCondition of (MyInput -> bool)

let impossibleCondition = StopCondition (fun _ -> false)

let moreComplicatedCondition = StopCondition <| fun inp ->
    inp.MyInt < int (round inp.MyFloat)
```

To call the function inside a `StopCondition`, unwrap it with a pattern:

```
let testStopCondition (StopCondition c) input = c input
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the examples. I'm still working through the four useful answers I got here. I think I need straighten out my understanding of a union constructor and that it is not a cast function. Thanks again.

Comment: In your example, having to unwrap the function with a pattern to call it gets at what I was missing in trying to (mis) use a DU. (And I know your answer is not the only one to get at this point.)

Comment: @RomnieEE Glad I could help. There is no "mis"use of a DU here at all; such single-case types are a perfectly normal and intended way to add type safety. It's also normal to give the type and its only case the same name; just keep in mind that the type and case constructor are not quite the same concept. (And the semantics as a pattern, again, are different.)

Answer (score 4):

You don't "make it be of type" `StoppingCondition`. You declare a value of type `StoppingCondition` and pass `Condition1` as the parameter of the DU case constructor:

```
let stop = StoppingCondition Condition1
```

That means, however, that every time you want to access the function contained in your single DU case, you have to pattern match over it in some way; that can become annoying.

You say you don't want just *any* functions that fulfill the signature to be valid as stopping conditions; however, it seems to be specific enough to avoid "accidentally" passing in an "inappropriate" function - with that, you could do something simpler - define `StoppingCondition` as a type alias for your specific function type:

```
type StoppingCondition = ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool
```

Now you can use `StoppingCondition` everywhere you need to specify the type, and the actual values you pass/return can be any functions that fulfill the signature `ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool`.

Comment: Thanks. I did make a type alias first. And it worked. I only tried the single case union as an exercise. (And my example tutorials online use simple types not functions for single case unions...) I need to work through your explanation of the union usage. But I think I'll end up with the alias in the code. I agree with you that it should be fine that way. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks also: mentioning that I would have to pattern match to use the function helps me see where I didn't really know how to use a DU. Really I was imaging the DU constructor as a cast function. And I forgot, or failed to learn, that even in the simpler case of say a single case for DU of `EmailAddress` of string--you have to deconstruct instances of that type to do "string things" to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the return type of a function is done like this:

```
let Condition1 lastRet nextRet i fl :StoppingCondition=
    true
```

of course, this won't compile as true is not of the correct type.

I suspect the actual definition you want is closer to

```
let Condition1  :StoppingCondition=
    true
```

though, as the type looks like it contains the function arguments.

Expanding on this, you can define such a function like:

```
let Condition1=fun a b c d -> StoppingCondition(fun a b c d -> whatever)
```

but this whole thing is pretty ugly.

Realistically, I think it is better to put all the functions in an array, which will force the types to match

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm getting closer. I think I agree with what you suspect. I want `Condition1`--not its return--to be of type `StoppingCondition`. So the second block is on that path. But now in that block `Condition1` no longer has any arguments. So I have nothing to work with. (The real function is of course not just to return `true`--I just elided the code.) So how do I get arguments in there too? They need names for me to use them. If this sounds really confusing or confused--it's because I am confused and making it confusing, without doubt. Thanks.

Comment: @RomnieEE - I think your approach is a little weird, but I gave a solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's weird because of my low understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems to me that you things you might want to with `StoppingCondition`s are to create some predefined type of stopping condition.

Here are some examples of some possible stopping conditions:

```
let stopWhenNextGreaterThanLast = StoppingCondition (fun last next _ _ -> next > last)

let stopWhenLastGreaterThanLast = StoppingCondition (fun last next _ _ -> last> next)
```

(I've underscored the parameters I'm not using in my stopping condition definition)

Hopefully you can see that both of these values of type `StoppingCondition`.

Then you might want a function to determine if the stopping condition had been met given some parameters:

```
let shouldStop stoppingCond last next i value = 
    match stoppingCond with
    |StoppingCondition f -> f last next i value
```

This function takes a stopping condition and the various states of your recursion and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether or not it should now stop.

This should be all you need to make use of this approach in practice.

---

You could extend this approach by doing something like this to cover multiple potential stopping conditions:

```
type StoppingCondition =
    | StoppingCondition of (ReturnType -> ReturnType -> int -> float -> bool)
    | Or of StoppingCondition * StoppingCondition
```

And modifying the `shouldStop` function

```
let rec shouldStop stoppingCond last next i value = 
    match stoppingCond with
    |StoppingCondition f -> f last next i value
    |Or (stp1, stp2) -> (shouldStop stp1 last next i value) || (shouldStop stp2 last next i value)
```

Now if we have a single condition, we stop when it's met or if we multiple conditions, we can check whether either of them are met.

Then you could `Or` together new stopping conditions from a base condition:

```
let stopWhenIIsEven = StoppingCondition (fun _ _ i _ -> i % 2 = 0)

let stopWhenValueIsZero = StoppingCondition (fun _ _ _ value -> value = 0.0)

let stopWhenIEvenOrValueZero = Or (stopWhenIIsEven, stopWhenValueIsZero)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the examples and explanation. I think one thing I'm doing is more or less confusing the constructor of a (single case) union with a cast function. I'm going to take a little longer to study all 4 good answers before I have to put a check on just one. But thanks again.

Comment: I'll mention here again, to be fair to all the answers, that having to unwrap the `StoppingCondition` points to where I think I'm off in my understanding of using a DU. Thanks for the example.